# How to split a string by a word but not with apostrophes

Tags: java, regex

I have a kind of SQL query which I want to split by 'AND' and 'OR'. The problem is that such keywords might be present in the query in apostrophes or quotes.

E.g. the following query:

```
attribute1 IS 'test AND attribute2 IS NOT 'test' AND attribute2 IN ('me and you', 'me or you')
```

should be split as follows:

```
attribute1 IS 'test
attribute2 IS NOT 'test'
attribute2 IN ('me and you', "me or you")
```

So basically any string in apostrophes or quotes ('me and you', "me or you") should not be processed. 
How can I do that with a single regex? Actually two, one to split by "OR" and another to split by "AND".

Thanks in advance for any help!
Mariusz

Comment: Since first `'test` has no closing quote so `AND` after that is also within single quotes.

Comment: `str.split("\\s+(OR|AND)\\s+")`

Comment: @AvinashRaj: This won't work if the text is `attribute1 IS 'test AND test2 AND attribute2...` with the first item being `attribute1 IS 'test AND test2`. Mariuszu, write your own parser.

Comment: I think @AvinashRaj solution should work as long as the `OR` and `AND`'s aren't inside quotes. [See this](https://regex101.com/r/hA4jD4/3). Parentheses will confuse it though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Wiktor already said, write your own parser. Trying to do it with a single regex may result in hard to read and maintain code.

Yet regexes may help reduce your own parser coding dramatically. Try the approach described here: http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html (the article is long and you may wish to skip directly to the *Match Tarzan but not "Tarzan"* section).

In brief: use this expression:

```
'.*?'|".*?"|(AND|OR)
```

*Demo (look for the green highlights): https://regex101.com/r/jC2jC9/1. NB: the expression in the demo is slightly more sophisticated than `'.*?'|".*?"|(AND|OR)` because by the latter I just wanted to outline the idea more clearly.*

Then in your Java code find all matches with `group(1)` defined. ANDs and ORs in quotes will be covered by the first two alternatives and won't be captured by the group. All you need now is to split the input string using `start()` and `end()` indexes of the matches with defined `group(1)`:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("'.*?'|\".*?\"|\\s*\\b(AND|OR)\\b\\s*", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
int nextPartPos = 0;
while (matcher.find()) {
    if (matcher.group(1) != null) {
        System.out.println(input.substring(nextPartPos, matcher.start()));
        nextPartPos = matcher.end();
        System.out.println("--> " + matcher.group(1) + " <--");
    }
}
if (nextPartPos < input.length()) {
    System.out.print(input.substring(nextPartPos));
}
```

Full demo code: https://ideone.com/3cmGhY

Final note: this code actually builds a flat list of subexpressions while you seen to need a hierarchy to implement AND/OR priority. I sure, it's not a big deal to add tree building feature in the code. I did not do this here just to concentrate on the main idea.